# Vincular linha do arquivo txt com o selecionado no meu chelistbox

Tags: c#

meu código traz dentro de um checklistbox o conteúdo de um arquivo txt. Cada linha desse arquivo(é também uma linha no meu checklistbox) é o conteúdo de uma variável que irei trocar em um documento Word. Preciso que ao selecionar no meu checklistbox o (nome do colaborador) ele traga pra mim de dentro do arquivo txt somente a linha do colaborador que selecionei pra mim armazenar na minha variável que ira dar o replace no Word. Segue código aonde eu leio todas as linhas e atribuo as minhas strings preciso manipular o conteúdo delas pra trazer somente a 'selecionada'.

PreencherReplace c = new PreencherReplace();

```
                string filePath = @"C:\Teste\Lista_col.txt";
                string line;
                string[] array  = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Teste\Lista_col.txt");

                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))

                    {
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] auxiliar = line.Split(';'); // faço um split separando onde possui barras e virgulas

                            c.codigo = auxiliar[0];
                            c.nome = auxiliar[1];
                            c.funcao = auxiliar[2];
                            c.setor = auxiliar[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Para isso, utilizo uma função:

```
public static void ImprimirArquivoWord(string arquivo, bool preview)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(arquivo, ReadOnly: true, Visible: preview);

    if (preview)
    {
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        aDoc.Activate();
        aDoc.PrintPreview();
    }
    else
    {
        aDoc.PrintOut();
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordApp).Quit(true);
    }
}
```

> Foi utilizada a referência para: `Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library` e `Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library`

Colocando no seu contexto:

```
foreach (FileInfo Arqui in ck_arquivos.CheckedItems)
{
    ImprimirArquivoWord(Arqui.FullName,false);
}
```

Comment: certo, amigo, nesse mesmo programa estou trocando algumas variáveis do documento Word(.docx) e depois imprimindo. Porem devido a meu 'object template' permitir estar setando apenas um arquivo ele não pega outro que eu tiver selecionado no meu checklistbox se não esse, você saberia uma forma de eu passar os demais arquivos meus pra ficar a minha escolha qual utilizar ? @Rovann Linhalis

Comment: @Lucão também realizo a troca de variáveis dentro do word. Mas para isso faço em uma função separada e salvo o arquivo em uma pasta temporária para isso. O fluxo é: Salvo o arquivo temporário. Chamo a função que troca as variáveis, e salva o arquivo. Chama a função que imprime. No seu contexto, basta colocar isso dentro do loop.

Comment: poderia me explicar melhor  como você faz pra passa mais de um arquivo Word pra mim verificar quais os selecionados através de codigo?

Comment: eu não passo mais de um arquivo na função ou no wordApp. Eu faço o loop que chama um arquivo por vez

Comment: amigos preciso também nesse mesmo programa o seguinte, eu já tenho o conteúdo de um arquivo txt lido, agora preciso trazer a linha do arquivo txt que eu selecionei  no meu checklistbox pra trocar em uma variável alguém pode me ajudar com esse vinculo?

Comment: edite a pergunta, explicando detalhadamente o que você precisa fazer, e eu irei alterar a resposta colocando o que você precisa.

Comment: mas esses arquivos que ele passa um por vez, como ele identifica o caminho onde estão esses arquivos  ?@Rovann Linhalis

Comment: eu salvo os arquivos que eu preciso, e armazeno o nome em variavel. depois faço o loop para impressão

Comment: entendi, quanto ao vinculo com o txt vou alterar a pergunta, você pode me ajudar ?

Comment: sim, só preciso entender o que você precisa fazer rs. Tente explicar o requisito do programa e o que você está tentando fazer